# How to fix a problem that bootstrap does not work even though everything is installed?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a popover using bootstrap
The library is installed for me below are the versions
And why does he not show me the design?
Anyone know what could be the problem?

**package.json***

```
 "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "~11.0.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.2",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.1.0",
        "firebase": "^8.1.2",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
```

**ANGULAR.JSON FILE:**

```
    "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          ],
"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", 
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```

my code:
**APP.COMPONENT.TS FILE:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  }
}

**APP.COMPONENT.HTML FILE:**

<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh2MR.png)  [Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K76i2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend initializing your popovers in the [AfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit) portion of the component lifecycle. This gives the component a chance to render the DOM, which jQuery depends on to select the popover elements.

Import `AfterContentInit` in place of `OnInit` and implement:

```js
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}
```

More on the lifecycle of Angular components: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Still the problem is in the presentation of the design from Bootstrap
Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not certain. I also haven't used ng-bootstrap, which I see is in your dependencies and might be affecting the default bootstrap functionality, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Okay,
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry I didn't think of this earlier, but it could be that your component's ViewEncapsulation is overriding Bootstrap. Try setting your ViewEncapsulation to `None` to allow your component to be styled by outside resources

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the styles.scss file

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```